# there is any body-parser for the http module Node.js

Tags: node.js

i am starting a new project in Node.js including the http module and I can't get to the body of the POST requests..
is there any middleware that can parse the body of the request?
i have tried the body-parser module , but it's not working with the http module.
and in **don't** want to use express only for the bodyparser middleware.
anybody got a solution for that?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: There's [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) for example, which [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) uses under the hood.

Comment: http module dosen't have the use method like express.

Comment: @RoiTal Is the issue just knowing how middleware should be invoked without a middleware framework (`.use()`)?

Comment: @RoiTal Also, what does "*i have tried the body-parser module*" look like? Can you please share that snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [body](https://github.com/Raynos/body), and for multipart bodies [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)